# Writing a function to optimize non-linear function nleqslv

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a system of non linear equations I want to solve, but it I am finding it hard to write the function to optimize in `nleqslv`.

Here is what I want to do mathimatically; I want to **minimize**:

[image]

So the a values are constants and I want to search for the x values that **minimize** this sum.

The problem is the insane amount of constraints on the values I have. Which mathematically are, in order:

[image]

So, the **cumulative sum** of the xs has to always be **bigger or equal to 0 and less or equal to scm if k<N**

However, **the cumulative sum of all the xs together has to be equal to 0**:

[image]

Finally, **each of the xi can be negative (except the first one) and is bound by a minimum and maximum value and these values are a function of the cumulative sum of all the xs before it**:

[image]

[image]

I set up fake values in R, in order to solve an easy version of this problem:

```
a <- c(20, 34, 22, 27)
scm <- 9300
finj <- function(x, inj_max){
  (1/(10 * x+1)) * inj_max
}

fwit <- function(x, wit_max){
  log( x+ 1) * wit_max
}
INJ <- 4650
WIT <- 4650
```

These functions translate the last constraint into:

[image]

```
fn <- function(x){
  
  #(0 <= x1) can't be expressed - so I put it x1 + 0.0000001
  c(
    x[1] - scm,
    x[1] + 0.0000001,
    x[1] + x[2] - scm,
    x[1] + x[2] + 0.0000001,
    x[1] + x[2] + x[3] - scm,
    x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + 0.0000001,
    x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4],
    #now start inj/wit constraints
    x[2] * (10 * x[1] +1) - INJ,
    x[2] + log(x[1] +1) * WIT + 0.0000001,
    x[3] * (10 * (x[1] + x[2]) +1) - INJ,
    x[3] + log(x[1] + x[2] +1) * WIT + 0.0000001,
    x[4] * (10 * (x[1] + x[2] + x[3]) +1) - INJ,
    x[4] + log(x[1] + x[2]  + x[3] + 1) * WIT+ 0.0000001
    )
  
}

nleqslv(c(4650, -4650, 4650, -4650), fn)
```

I wrote this `function` also and tried to solve it but I got the error:

```
Error in nleqslv(c(4650, -4650, 4650, -4650), fn) : 
  Length of fn result <> length of x!
```

It's logical that I get this error since I have so many constraints, so I don't know how I can solve this optimisation problem or how I can rewrtie the constraints to not have this error.

Comment: nleqslv is for square systems of nonlinear equations.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen what are my options then ? I am open to using other software.

Comment: I would use a general-purpose NLP solver. Also I would use extra variables to model the cumulative sum: `y(i) = y(i-1)+x(i)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want `nleqslv`, which is for systems of nonlinear equations. You are trying to minimize a single function with multiple arguments. `optim` from base R should work.

As for the constraints, each parameter is bounded with a minimum and maximum, but the bounds are sequentially dependent, which makes it a little trickier. One approach is to perform sequential transformations of the inputs into their allowable space. This allows the function to accept any real values as inputs because it will automatically transform them to meet the constraints. I used `pnorm` for the transformation.

The other thing to consider is that the problem has `N - 1` degrees of freedom since  `sum(x)` must be 0. The way to handle that is to pass only `N - 1` paramters to the function to be optimized and then set `x[N]` to be `-sum(x[-N])`.

Here's some example code using your "fake values":

```
scm <- 9300
INJ <- 4650
WIT <- 4650

a <- c(20, 34, 22, 27)

fT <- function(xT) {
  # transforms the input values xT into values that meet the problem constraints
  x <- numeric(length(xT) + 1)
  mini <- 0             # the minimum for parameter 1
  maxi <- min(scm, INJ) # the maximum for parameter 1
  x[1] <- (maxi - mini)*(pnorm(xT[1])) + mini # transform xT[1] to a value between mini and maxi
  xcumsum <- x[1]
  
  for (i in 2:length(xT)) {
    mini <- max(-xcumsum, -WIT*log(xcumsum + 1))     # calculate the minimum for parameter i
    maxi <- min(scm - xcumsum, INJ/(10*xcumsum + 1)) # calculate the maximum for parameter i
    x[i] <- (maxi - mini)*(pnorm(xT[i])) + mini      # transform xT[i] to a value between mini and maxi
    xcumsum <- xcumsum + x[i]
  }
  
  x[i + 1] <- -xcumsum
  return(x)
}

fn <- function(xT) {
  return(sum(a*fT(xT)))
}

# optimize fn using a vector of N - 1 zeros as the initial guess
> optim(numeric(length(a) - 1), fn)
$par
[1]  17.3 -23.2   9.2

$value
[1] -88350

$counts
function gradient 
      32       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

The values returned by `optim$par` are transformed values. Invert the transform using `fT`:

```
x <- fT(optim(numeric(length(a) - 1), fn)$par)
> x
[1]  4650 -4650  4650 -4650
```

Passing `x[1:3]` to `fn` gives the minimized function value:

```
> fn(head(x, -1))
[1] -88350
```

Which checks out with calculating `fn` manually:

```
> sum(a*x)
[1] -88350
```

UPDATE1:
From the comments about converging to a sub-optimal local minimum, I tried the various methods available for `optim` that are applicable here, and the "L-BFGS-B" method does find the global for this case, but it's hard to say if it will generally converge to the global minimum:

```
cm <- 4650
INJ <- 4650
WIT <- 4650
a <- c(20, 19, 22, 27)

> optim(numeric(length(a) - 1), fn)$value
[1] -32550
> optim(numeric(length(a) - 1), fn, method = "BFGS")$value
[1] -32550
> optim(numeric(length(a) - 1), fn, method = "CG")$value
[1] -32550
> optim(numeric(length(a) - 1), fn, method = "L-BFGS-B")$value
[1] -37200
> optim(numeric(length(a) - 1), fn, method = "SANN")$value
[1] -32550.1
```

UPDATE2:
In response the the question about how the above code handles `N - 1` parameters, I'll point out a few things:

1. an `N - 1` length vector is passed to `optim` (see `numeric(length(a) - 1)`)
2. `fT` accepts a vector (`xT`) and outputs a vector of length `length(xT) + 1` (see `x <- numeric(length(xT) + 1)` and `x[i + 1] <- -xcumsum`)
3. I never created the object `N`, but `i = N - 1` once the `for` loop completes, so `x[i + 1] <- -xcumsum` affects `x` the same as `N <- length(a); x[N] <- -sum(x[-N])` since `xcumsum` is a lagging cumulative sum

Comment: I just fixed an error in the formula for `maxi`:  `maxi <- min(scm , INJ/(10*xcumsum + 1))` should have been `maxi <- min(scm - xcumsum, INJ/(10*xcumsum + 1))`

Comment: You are a GOD ! Also, you already know why I need to solve these equations since you adjusted the parameters of xi to take into account minimum and maximum injection/withdrawal !

Comment: "The way to handle that is to pass only N - 1 paramters to the function to be optimized and then set x[N] to be -sum(x[-N])" where and how did you do this in the code ?

Comment: Also try it with scm <- 4650 and a <- c(20, 19, 22, 27) it tells you to have x1 >0 and x2 == 0 but it would be better in that case to have x2 == 4650 and not x1

Comment: Just saw this. You're right. `optim` isn't giving an optimal solution in that case. `x <- c(0, 4650, 0, -4650)` gives `sum(a*x) = -37200` vs the `optim` solution of -32550. My guess is that it is finding a local minimum. Maybe a different method or another package will do better. I'll poke around.

Comment: Changing the initial guess gives the correct answer: `optim(c(-5, 5, 5), fn)`, but that is disappointing behavior for an optimizer.

Comment: @user9396820 Just added an update showing the effect of changing the method.

Comment: dude if I could upvote you a million times I would. Thx a lot you are a legend